# Django keeps rendering the same page

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to set up navigation with Django, however, each time I try to navigate it goes back to the same page again.
Please help, any advice will be appreciated. Thank you!

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

#from . import views
# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            #raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            #user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('/templates')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'templates/signup_form.html', {'form': form})
```

in Project the file called 
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', include('website.urls')),
    url(r'^signup/', include('website.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

in the app website urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from . import views
#
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.login, name=''),
    url(r'^login/', login, {'template_name': 'templates/login.html'}),
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup, name = 'signup')




    #url(r'^login/$', index,{{'template_name': 'templates/index.html' }})
]
```

Comment: `url(r'^', views.login, name=''),` this may be your problem.  `^` matches beginning-of-line, and every string has a beginning, so this expression matches all strings.  Perhaps you meant `^$`, i.e. a blank string?

Answer (score 2):

The URL patterns are matched from top to bottom. Your first urlpattern is matching anything it sees, so django sends all requests to `views.login`.

Try putting that row at the bottom of the list

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^login/', login, {'template_name': 'templates/login.html'}),
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup, name = 'signup')

    url(r'^', views.login, name=''),}})
```

]

Comment: it still did not switch to the signup page

Comment: Your `login` view refers to `login.html` whereas your signup view refers to `templates/signup_form.html`. Given that one has the `templates/` prefixed and the other doesn't, it suggests you might need to check how your template directories have been set up. If it is the `login` view that is failing then try add the templates prefix, or else compare your `TEMPLATES` setting to the documentation here [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#templates)